# Repair wrong translation

Tags: liferay, hook, translation

There are a lot of places in liferay portal where translation to my language (sk_SK) is wrong. Is it possible to rewrite those bad translations with hook? (Any other idea is welcomed...)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You haven't access to the language files? Otherwise you could fix these wrong translations and send them to Liferay. Or contact Liferay and explain what you want to do. Maybe they will send you the appropiate files.

Comment: When you're done with your translation correction, please consider giving back on https://translate.liferay.com/ or through github - also, you might be able to download a newer translation there or in the current master release. (otherwise, Gautam has given quite a good answer). More information on the translation process here: https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Translating+Liferay+using+Pootle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can do it.

in your `liferay-hook.xml` file add entry for language file which you want to override,
like in your case `Language_sk.properties`

```
<hook>   
    <language-properties>content/Language_sk.properties</language-properties>    
</hook>
```

you can check this file in Liferay source code from below location

```
LiferaySrcFolder\portal-impl\src\content\Language_sk.properties
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I will check if it will solve my problem and if yes, then I'll accept this answer.