# How can we change the language of portlet header?

Tags: liferay, locale, liferay-6

I need to change portlet name,when the locale is changed()
Like if a portlet name is "Activities" then after change the language it must be display as "activités".

Thanks

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497831/repair-wrong-translation/23503493#23503493

Answer (score 0):

For any portlet added on the page you can set custom title for each of the different langauges in the `Look & Feel` tab from Configuration as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hello prakash! i use this code to display <%=initialPage.getUserName() %> wiki page creator but  its unable to display creator name!

Comment: How is this related to the question you have asked? Or is this some different question? if it is different then please create another question.

Comment: I follow this link and its working fine for me 
http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/14839403